# How can I retrieve rows in a text file

Tags: c, parsing, text, filestream

I started programing in language C, and I have some problems with reading text files. Let me explain.

I have one file text which is organized like this :

```
Tony 
12.23
John
09.45
Tayris
03.99
```

I would like to retrieve all notes less than ten and display them, but I can't...

Does anybody could help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag appropriately. Also, what code do you have by now that does not work?

Comment: @ysap, tagging `homework` is discouraged, see: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C provides four functions that can be used to read files from disk:

1. **fscanf()**

   field oriented function.
2. **fgets()**

   line oriented function.
3. **fgetc()**

   character oriented function
4. **fread()**

   block oriented function.

See **[this article](http://www.mrx.net/c/readfunctions.html)** for more information.

Comment: No it's not an homework, it's my self training about this programing language

Comment: I believe you meant this in reply to ysap's comment above.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to reply to ysap's comment

Comment: For future reference, there is an "add comment" link in the top section which you may use to reply to comments in that area of the page. Also, if someone has posted a response which answers your question please click on the checkmark next to their answer. I see you are relatively new to the site, so I hope this brief tutorial will help you on your way.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `fgets` function. It will return until (and including) the end of string character (you can strip it from the destination string if you want).

http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~iancooke/osstuff/ccc.html offers an example:

> Here's a more complicated example.
>   Readline() uses fgets() to read up to
>   MAX_LINE - 1 characters into the
>   buffer 'in'. It strips preceding
>   whitespace and returns a pointer to
>   the first non-whitespace character.

```
 char *Readline(char *in) {
   char *cptr;

   if (cptr = fgets(in, MAX_LINE, stdin)) {
     /* kill preceding whitespace but leave \n 
        so we're guaranteed to have something*/
     while(*cptr == ' ' || *cptr == '\t') {
       cptr++;
     }
     return cptr;    
    } else {
     return 0;
   }
 }
```

That should be enough I think.